# WebView load crashes on url opening

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, utm, utm-tracking

I have an app that retrieves urls from a json and when the user clicks on a button the UIWebView opens to the url. The problem is that when I added utm codes to the urls the app started to crash and the UIWebView returns nil. My guess is that the symbol "&" cannot be resolved by the app and it crashes. I tried to modify the url by putting the encoded symbol "%26" but then I have the problem that Google Analytics doesn't read it...
Is there a way to make the "&" symbol work? Thank you in advance.

I call the UiWebView this way:

```
self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: self.link)!))
```

Comment: Print `self.link`. `&` is a valid character in a `URL`. A space isn't for instance. But without the value of `self.link`, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Printing it I see that the & symbol looks like this "&#038;" so the problem is that it converts in html? I don't know why it does this

Comment: what's `self.link`?

Comment: It's the string containing the url of the page, I retrieve from a json

Comment: Whatever that string is, it obviously what causes the crash. But without seeing it, nobody can tell you why the code is crashing. As SO says "The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem." Can't reproduce it without knowing the string.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it's hard to tell what exactly is wrong with your string that you are trying to convert into an URL without seeing it.

However, to avoid unexpected crashes, you should safe unwrap your URL instead of explicitly unwrapping it by using `URL(string: self.link)!`.

You could for example create an if let:

```
if let safeURL = URL(string: self.link) {
self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url)
}
```